# Pyqt5 Start-Stop Button

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to make a simple start/stop button. But I couldn't get the stop button to work. Can you help me with this?

```
def pressed(self):             
    self.infoLabel.clear()
    self.infoLabel.setText(self.infoLabel.text()+ " On The Way! Go chat.")
    self.goButton.setEnabled(False)
    self.stopPushButton.setEnabled(True)        
    while True:            
        randomTimer = float(random.uniform(6.2, 7.5))
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(randomTimer*1000)    
        myKeyboard.type("ABC")  
        myKeyboard.press(Key.enter)
        self.infoLabel.clear()
        self.infoLabel.setText(QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog).text()+(" You typed ABC " + str(randomTimer)[0:5] + " seconds apart..."))            
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(3000)
        self.infoLabel.setText(QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog).text()+(" Continue.. Wait the next type."))
        if self.stopPushButton.isEnabled(False):
            break            


def stopped(self):
    self.infoLabel.clear()
    self.infoLabel.setText(self.infoLabel.text()+ " Stopped!")        
    self.goButton.setEnabled(True)
    self.stopPushButton.setEnabled(False)
```

Comment: Define "But I couldn't get the stop button to work.", add context and all of the codes, can't help with that much details.

Comment: don't use `while True` loops in GUIs because it blocks mainloop and GUI can't work. You should rather use some Timer to execute function every few milliseconds. This is rule for any GUI (PyQt, tkinter, wxPython, PyGTk) and any language.

Answer (score 0):

stopPushButton is an instance of QPushButton, it will never be equal to false, use the `.enabled` property to check if it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Make the stop button togglable and check `if self.stopPushButton.isChecked()` in the loop, then reset its state in the `stopped` method for cleanliness.

```py
    ...
    self.stopPushButton.setCheckable(True)
    ...


def pressed(self):             
    self.infoLabel.clear()
    self.infoLabel.setText(self.infoLabel.text()+ " On The Way! Go chat.")
    self.goButton.setEnabled(False)
    self.stopPushButton.setEnabled(True)
    while True:            
        randomTimer = float(random.uniform(16.2,19.5))
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(randomTimer*1000)    
        myKeyboard.type("ABC")  
        myKeyboard.press(Key.enter)
        self.infoLabel.clear()
        self.infoLabel.setText(QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog).text()+(" You typed ABC " + str(randomTimer)[0:5] + " seconds apart..."))
        if self.stopPushButton.isChecked():
            break
        

def stopped(self):
    self.infoLabel.clear()
    self.infoLabel.setText(self.infoLabel.text()+ " Stopped!")        
    self.goButton.setEnabled(True)
    self.stopPushButton.setEnabled(False) 
    self.stopPushButton.setChecked(False)
```

Comment: İt didn't work. The loop still continues.

Comment: Yes, because you are using a loop which blocks the main event loop and the buttons are not processed until the loop ends. You could either move the content of the loop to a method and have a QTimer tick trigger that method, or the quick and dirty way is to add `QApplication.processEvents()` before `self.stopPushButton.isChecked():`.